# Problema com animação de valores no Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tenho um problema com uma animação de transição numérica.

Eu queria que a animação sempre continuasse a partir do último número gerado, mas está sempre repetindo a primeira transição de valor feita

Já procurei alguém que tivesse problema parecido, mas não encontrei

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  Animation numberTransitionAnimation;
  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  animationController = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 1), vsync: this);
  numberTransitionAnimation = IntTween(begin: currentNumber, end: newNumber).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.linear));
  }

  int selectedNumber;
  int currentNumber = 0;
  int newNumber = 0;
  int total = 2000;


  void selectNumber(selectedNumber){
    
    newNumber = selectedNumber + currentNumber;
    
    currentNumber = newNumber;
    
    animationController.reset();
    animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animationController,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child){
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(numberTransitionAnimation.value.toString() + " / $total"),
                  // \/ Test to see if the method is working
                  Text(currentNumber.toString()),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: () => selectNumber(100), child: Text('100')),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: ()=> selectNumber(200), child: Text('200')),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: ()=> selectNumber(300), child: Text('300')),
                ],
              )
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Já tentei usar o `setState (){}`, mas não deu certo. Engraçado que está atualizando valores do teste mesmo sem o setState.

Já tentei usar `animationController.forward(from: currentNumber.toDouble());`, mas também não adiantou.

Até imaginei que o problema fosse por talvez as variáveis estarem com o mesmo valor no momento da inicialização, mas não é. Dei um valor inicial de 0 para `currentNumber` e 200 para `newNumber`, a animação é feita, porém o valor de `currentNumber` já mudou e a animação não atualiza, continua animando de 0 a 200.

Já tentei também usar `animationController.reverse()`, sem sucesso.

Grato desde já por você se disponibilizar em ler o meu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o Widget `TweenAnimationBuilder` para deixar a coisa mais simples.

Nos meus testes, trabalhar com o valor como *double* surgiu uma animação mais fluida, então aconselho que trate o *int* como um *double* apenas na questão da animação.

> Transforma seu valor `int = 2` para `double = 2.0`, faz a animação e
> exibe o `int = 2` corretamente.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }

  int currentNumber = 0;
  int selectedNumber = 0;
  int total = 2000;


  void selectNumber(int number){
    setState((){
      selectedNumber = number;
      currentNumber += selectedNumber;
    });
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                    TweenAnimationBuilder(
                        tween: Tween<double>(begin: (currentNumber - selectedNumber).toDouble(), end: currentNumber.toDouble()),
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                        builder: (BuildContext context, double valor, Widget child) {
                            return Text("${valor.round()} / $total");
                        },
                    ),
                    // \/ Test to see if the method is working
                    Text(currentNumber.toString()),
                    RaisedButton(onPressed: () => selectNumber(100), child: Text('100')),
                    RaisedButton(onPressed: ()=> selectNumber(200), child: Text('200')),
                    RaisedButton(onPressed: ()=> selectNumber(300), child: Text('300')),
                ],
            )
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Você pode saber mais em [TweenAnimationBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TweenAnimationBuilder-class.html).

Comment: Obrigado pelo ajuda, deu certo!

Sou iniciante na programação, então tenho o vício de achar que as coisas só podem ser feitas conforme aprendidas por tutoriais. Seu código ficou mais claro e polido que o meu, e o melhor, funcionou. 
Não sabia que dava para incrementar uma variável com outra variável, não sabia da existência do `TweenAnimationBuilder`, etc.

Muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Aos poucos você vai conhecendo melhor carinha! Vai firme ai

Answer (score 0):

Experimente re-criar o objeto de animação com os valores atualizados:

```
void selectNumber(selectedNumber){
 [...]

    numberTransitionAnimation = IntTween(begin: currentNumber, end: newNumber).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.linear));

    animationController.reset();
    animationController.forward();
  }
```

Quando o objeto `numberTransitionAnimation` foi criado da primeira vez, ele usou os valores daquele momento de `newNumber`e `currentNumber`. Ele não vai ser re-gerado caso essas variáveis mudem de valor.

Obs: Não ficou claro exatamente o quê você deseja fazer ao modificar a animação, mas o seguinte código:

```
currentNumber = newNumber;
```

Faz as variáveis de início e fim da animação serem iguais. (Então perdendo o significado de uma animação.) Sua intenção era continuar do mesmo ponto de forma continua? Talvez algo do tipo resolva: `currentNumber = numberTransitionAnimation.value;`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Sou iniciante no mundo da programação e existem coisas que eu acho que só podem ser feitas do modo que aprendi em tutoriais. Não sabia que dava para acrescentar o `IntTween` dentro do método.

Eu suspeitava da parte que a animação não ia ser re-gerada com a mudança das variáveis, mas não sabia como resolver.

Sobre `currentNumber = newNumber;`, era uma linha de comando para que o novo número gerado em `newNumber` fosse armazenado em `currentNumber`, já que ele ia ser o novo número atual e ficasse pronto para quando o botão que chama o método fosse clicado novamente.